# Python list: how to make it ordered and get rid of duplicates

Tags: python, list

I'm a novice in Python and my homework is to take a list with a bunch of numbers in it and

1. make the list ordered from lowest number to highest
2. get rid of duplicate numbers.

**This must be accomplished with loops**

My code so far:

```
numbers = [84, 79, 66, 69, 79, 82, 78, 79, 84, 84, 79, 66, 69, 84,
           72, 65, 84, 73, 83, 84, 72, 69, 81, 85, 69, 83, 84, 73, 79, 78]
ordered = []
while numbers != []:
    min = numbers[0]
    for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] < min:
            min = numbers[i]
    ordered.append(min)
    j = 0
    while j < len(numbers):
        if numbers[j] == min:
            numbers.pop(j)
        j += 1
print(ordered)
```

And the output:

```
[65, 66, 69, 72, 73, 78, 79, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 84, 84, 85]
```

So task1 is okay but task2 is only accomplished at some points not all.
I can't figure out why?
Thank you in advance for any help!
P.S.: I already solved the problem in another way but it just keeps bugging me why this posted idea of mine didn't work.

Comment: why not just `sorted(set(numbers))`.

Comment: FWIW, and I know you didn't ask, but `ordered = sorted(set(numbers))` will solve this in just one line of code.

Comment: Put `j += 1` under an `else`. When you pop an item you don't want to increment the index because a duplicate could have slided into its place.

Comment: Thank you that was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have provided shorter and more efficient ways of doing this, but you asked specifically what goes wrong with *your* approach. The problem is in this bit:

```py
    j = 0
    while j < len(numbers):
        if numbers[j] == min:
            numbers.pop(j)
        j += 1
```

What happens if `min` occurs twice back to back? Let's say for example that `min == 3`, and the list is `[1, 3, 3, 7]`.

- For `j == 0`, `numbers[j] == 1` so we don't pop it, and increment `j`.
- For `j == 1`, `numbers[j] == 3` so we remove the element `1` and increment `j`. The list is now `[1, 3, 7]`.
- For `j == 2`, `numbers[j] == 7` so we don't pop it, and we're done.

Whoops! We have skipped over the second `3` because it moved back one position when we popped its predecessor, while `j` moved forwards one position at the same time.

The solution is to only increment `j` if we didn't remove anything, because we need to re-check the element at position `j` after we removed its predecessor:

```py
    j = 0
    while j < len(numbers):
        if numbers[j] == min:
            numbers.pop(j)
        else:
            j += 1
```

Let's verify that the loop is still guaranteed to terminate. Each iteration, either `j` becomes larger, or `len(numbers)` becomes smaller, so eventually they will meet and `j < len(numbers)` becomes false. So we're good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bubble sort.(If you need another sorting method, just replace it)

```
numbers = [84, 79, 66, 69, 79, 82, 78, 79, 84, 84, 79, 66, 69, 84,
    72, 65, 84, 73, 83, 84, 72, 69, 81, 85, 69, 83, 84, 73, 79, 78]

def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
    no_dub = []
    for i in arr:
        if i not in no_dub:
            no_dub.append(i)
    return no_dub
bubble_sort(numbers)
```

The result:

```
[65, 66, 69, 72, 73, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a small addition:

```
    while j < len(numbers):
    if numbers[j] == min:
        numbers.pop(j)
        j -= 1             #increment should not advance if you pop a number
    j += 1
```

Then it will work

Answer (score -1):

`set` will remove duplicates

`sorted` will sort it

```
sorted(list(set([65, 66, 69, 72, 73, 78, 79, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 84, 84, 85])))
[65, 66, 69, 72, 73, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85]
```

Comment: `sorted()` can also take a `set` as parameter, so `list()` can be left out.

Comment: Read the question. The OP is required to use loop  to accomplish his goal